# How can I veto a Drag'n'Drop event from a Primefaces 3 tree?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I noticed that a tree branch disappears if you drag a tree node onto one of its children.

Try it here:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/treeDragDrop.jsf

How can I keep this from happening ?

Comment: I suggest to report this as bug to PF guys.

Comment: I submitted this to the forum first.
I think it may be solvable with event handling.